# Why does increasing hscale produce overfull hbox?

Tags: geometry, prelim2e

I would like help understanding why increasing the proportion of the page available for text produces an overfull `\hbox` error. In the output, this results in my preliminary markers being skewed right.

The problem doesn't seem to affect regular text or (as far as I'm aware) headers/footers. Rather, it seems to affect only text added by packages such as `prelim2e` which add text below the page footer, for example.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,svn-multi}
    \svnidlong
        {$HeadURL: file:///svn/myproject/tweaked-branch/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/tex/latex/something/something.sty $}
        {$LastChangedBy: cfr $}
        {$LastChangedRevision: 19567 $}
        {$LastChangedDate: 2014-04-16 19:46:05 +0100 (Mer, 16 Ebr 2014) $}
% \usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hscale=.875]{geometry}
\usepackage{prelim2e}
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\centering \small \textsf{Draft --- pdf\LaTeX{}ed --- \today}}%
    \@ifpackageloaded{svn-multi}{%
        \newsavebox{\prelimtxt}
        \sbox{\prelimtxt}{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                    \urlstyle{sf}%
                    \centering \small \textsf{Draft --- \today\ --- Revision \svnrev\ --- \svnyear--\svnmonth--\svnday\ \svnhour:\svnminute:\svnsecond}\\[1em]
                    \centering \tiny \textsf{\svnkw{HeadURL}}%
                    }% end parbox
            }% end sbox
        \renewcommand{\PrelimText}{\usebox{\prelimtxt}}
        }{}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Overfull hbox error with marker skewed right]

If I merely load `geometry` but do not change the defaults, I do not get the error and the preliminary marker is (at least closer to being) correctly centred:

[image: No error]

If I don't load `geometry` at all, I get no error but the preliminary marker is skewed to the left rather than the right:

[image: No error without marker skewed left]

I guess what is puzzling to me (and which probably reveals my naivete) is that *prima facie* I would expect providing more room for text to *reduce* overfull hboxes at least for single lines where the problem isn't merely an artefact of altered line breaking. If the box isn't overfull in *less* space, how does it become overfull in *more*?

Comment: We could put `\kern-0.0625\textwidth` in front of the `\parbox` command, but it would be only workaround not a real solution.